# Prevent AngularJs content flash on $scope update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I update my `$scope` like so in a controller

```
$scope.item = "Hello";
```

Then the whole DOM for `item` seems to be removed and then added again. This seems fine, but if I have a list of `items` and do

```
$scope.items = Resource.query();
```

To update all the items then all of the DOM for `items` is removed and then re-added, this looks a broken and clumsy - is there anyway around this removing and then adding of the DOM elements when `$scope` is updated?

This issue is further exasperated if `$scope.items` and its children are used inside several `ng-repeat` statements as all of those `ng-repeat` sections are removed and then re-added.

**EDIT**

I have read this and feel that this is the issue https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

That I have so much "stuff" going on the `$digest` is just slow. I am working on an example but in the mean time imagine this try of data

```
{
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: "name1", 
        something: {
            id: 10,
            name: "something10"
            else: {
                id: 15,
                name: "else15"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there are 20 such objects all with nested objects - this appears to be the issue. That there are so many objects being parsed and bound to the DOM that the `$watchers` are just taking a long time to go over everything.

**EDIT 2**

I made this demo, perhaps I am using resource wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/QOickL0Dyi8jmuvG9mzN

But the items are replaced every 5 seconds, on replace they all disappear and then reappear. This is the issue I am having.

Comment: Please provide a demo of your problem, but imho it seems you have too much stuff in the `$digest` cycle, so inevitable the app slows down.

Comment: OK, I will work on a fiddle - does that mean this should not happen if I have less stuff? Any tips on improving this issue?

Comment: This seems like it could be solved with CSS, but we'd need to see your html

Comment: Not sure how much stuff you have got right now, so hard to say if limiting it will for sure help. One other thing is that with each query you assign completely new array [internal hashes used to track elements in `ng-repeat` are lost and angular treats them as new values] -- if there are not too many changes then it would be much better to modify the array in place.

Comment: I have made an edit. This `modify the array in place` is interesting - does that stop the heavy hitting of `$digest`

Comment: Really interested in how much data u have.

Comment: I do not think its that much, its perhaps 1 object, with various primitive attributes and then 5 child objects. Those child objects have 1 or top objects themselves. So its not that much. I am hoping `track by` will help.

Comment: See my EDIT 2 for a demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'll take a look at $resource [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), you'll see that the correct way of manipulation with data - to use callback function

Instead of

```
 $scope.items = Resource.query();
```

Try

```
Resource.query(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
});
```

Comment: Can you check out my second edit. I am using `$resource` incorrectly? IN that the bind to the `$scope` should be in the Resource rather than the Controller?

Comment: Thanks for this example. From what I can see your `awesome` is what I want! Looks like I need to be assigning values to `$scope` inside my Resource rather than in my Controllers?

Comment: Yes. Immediate invoking returns an empty reference. And only when data arrives - view re-renders.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, a massive help!

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem when using *ng-repeat*. In order to track the objects the directive itself by default adds additional property to every object in the array (*$$hashkey*). And whenever new object is added or removed from the array the same is happening for it's associating DOM element. When the array is replaced with new array (ex. returned from the server) as you mentioned all the DOM elements representing objects from the previous array are removed and replaced with new DOM elements for the new objects. This is simply because the new objects in the array does not have the *$$hashkey* property even though they may be semantically the same.

A solution for this common problem came in Angular 1.2 version with the *track by* clause. You can find more detailed explanation about it in [this](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/) post.

In your case the objects in the array have an *'id'* property which it's a good candidate for tracking them if you can guarantee it's uniqueness. So using ng-repeat like this will improve it's performance.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
  <!-- tpl -->
</div>
```

Comment: That's really good to know! Thanks. I'll have a read. Quick question: if the ID doesn't change, does that mean the DOM won't be updated, even if other fields have changed?

Comment: If the ID does not change the DOM element will not be removed and then re-added as previously, the content will always be updated because of the watchers. Shortly you get the same behavior but without replacing the main DOM element that represents the object.

Comment: I do not think this is the issue, because even with vastly simple data its the same. See my second edit.

Comment: This wasn't the issue in the end, but was helpful. Do those IDs need to be globally unique within Ang? I tried it and it exploded with a dupes issue.

Comment: Thanks! The answer to your question is: no only in the array of items.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ngCloak directive?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Yes. But the issue isn't hiding the '{{}}' elements of the template. It's when the '$scope' is updated via AJAX calls.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Why you didn't update items in the query promise (I think it's because Resource.query return an ngResource object which is populated by after success) : Resource.query().$promise.then(function(result){$scope.items=result;});

Comment: But does that stop the `$digest` being hit all the time? Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't think that stop the `$digest` performance issue because of use of `ng-repeat` but I think it could solve the problem of content flash. I think your problem is that during content loading, the `items` array is empty.

Comment: I already use `ng-cloak` which is for stopping `{{ }}` from displaying, this works fine. Its the updates to the `$scope` that are the issue, not the pre-rendered template code.

Comment: And did you try `Resource.query().$promise.then(function(result{$scope.items=result;});` instead of `$scope.items = Resource.query();` ?